# Difference between WCAG 1.2.3 Audio description or media alternative (prerecorded ) and 1.2.5 Audio description (prerecorded)

Tags: accessibility

Both guideline says about the video content should have audio description so that blind user or low vision user can still use the webpage without the video.
what is the difference between these 2 guideline ?

1.2.3 which is level A

1.2.5  which is level AA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to the Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (WCAG) 1.2.3 and 1.2.5, both guidelines address the need for providing audio description for video content to ensure accessibility for blind or low vision users. However, there is a difference in the level of compliance required and the specific context they cover.

WCAG 1.2.3 Audio description or media alternative (prerecorded) - Level A:
This guideline, falls under Level A conformance, itemphasizes the importance of providing an audio description or an alternative for prerecorded video content. It states that if there is visual-only content (e.g., videos without audio or with significant visual information not conveyed through audio), an alternative version should be provided. This can include an audio description, a text transcript, or other accessible formats that convey the content to users who cannot access the visual information. The main objective is to ensure that blind or low vision users can understand the information presented in the video.

Example: If you have a prerecorded video tutorial without any audio narration, you would need to provide an alternative version with an audio description that explains the visual content, allowing visually impaired users to understand the video's context.

WCAG 1.2.5 Audio description (prerecorded) - Level AA:
This guideline, which falls under Level AA conformance, focuses specifically on providing audio description for prerecorded video content. It states that if a video contains important visual information that is not described in the audio track, an additional audio description should be provided to convey that information. This ensures that blind or low vision users can fully comprehend the visual content presented in the video.

Example: Suppose you have a prerecorded video demonstration of a product that showcases visual steps. In addition to the regular audio narration, you would need to include an audio description that provides details about the visual elements, such as gestures, actions, or important visual cues, allowing visually impaired users to follow along accurately.

While both guidelines address the need for audio description in prerecorded video content, WCAG 1.2.3 (Level A) emphasizes providing an alternative version or media alternative, while WCAG 1.2.5 (Level AA) specifically focuses on adding audio description to convey visual information not covered in the regular audio track. It's important to consider these guidelines to ensure that blind and low vision users can access and understand the video content on your website.